# Load data into table on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some question about syntax. I want to load data on inside of Region table which is has id and names. Id come many and one of the region have the same id but 20 times. I have Region.txt. So i want to load this text document inside the table. I used this:

`mysql > LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/nasimjon/Documents/Region.txt' INTO TABLE Region -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`

The come error:

`ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.`

Thanks for advance.

Comment: ...and what is your MySQL version number ?

Comment: 5.5.32 Thanks for all hints.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

> LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been
>   configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with
>   --local-infile=0

If your server var is already configured as 1

```
show variables like 'local_infile';
```

You can try execute your `LOAD DATA LOCAL` connecting to he server using:

```
mysql --local-infile -u***** -p**** -hyourhost
```

More info about this kind of behaviour here: [6.1.6 Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html)